# Jquery different versions. Jquery Searchable Autosuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have to use two jquery API's, "jquery-1.8.3.js" and "jquery-ui.js" in my code.
But there are already older versions of jquery. And because of this the form is not working properly.

So I search on net for solution and found, we can use

```
<script>
    var jq13 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

But I have to api's, so I created two variables but still it is not working.
This is my code:-

```
<script>
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            var input,
                that = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
                wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                    .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
                    .insertAfter( select );

            function removeIfInvalid(element) {
                var value = $( element ).val(),
                    matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( value ) + "$", "i" ),
                    valid = false;
                select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                    if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                        this.selected = valid = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if ( !valid ) {
                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                    $( element )
                        .val( "" )
                        .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
                        .tooltip( "open" );
                    select.val( "" );
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
                    }, 2500 );
                    input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                    return false;
                }
            }

            input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( wrapper )
                .val( value )
                .attr( "title", "" )
                .addClass( "ui-combobox-input" )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        that._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        if ( !ui.item )
                            return removeIfInvalid( this );
                    }
                })
                .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

            input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

            $( "<a>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                //.attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .tooltip()
                .appendTo( wrapper )
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" )
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visible
                    if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                        input.autocomplete( "close" );
                        removeIfInvalid( input );
                        return;
                    }

                    // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                    $( this ).blur();

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                    input.focus();
                });                    
        },

        destroy: function() {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
        }
    });
})( jQuery );

$(function() {
    $( "#driver_uuidHOS" ).combobox();       
});
</script>
```

And I have declared two variables:-

```
<script src="js/new/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq13 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="js/new/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq131 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

So please tell me where I have to use jq13 and where jq131 in my code. This code is for searchable autosuggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you remove the old version of jQuery? You could try replacing `$` with `jQuery` in the code.

Comment: I cannot do that as there are many form in the project and client don't want these changes.

Answer (score 0):

After you load the first version, you can assign it to a variable.

```
var jq13 = jQuery.noConflict(true); // as you did
```

And then load your second jQuery version. The first one you load can be accessed with jq13(...) while the second one can be accessed with $(...).

No need for assgning variable to second script...

Comment: A.V actually there are already few more Jquery API, so I have to use these two along with them. These two API are used only for the function in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You want to load one version of jQuery, then all the plugins for that version, then turn on no conflict mode. You can repeat this process as many times as you'd like (once for each version of jQuery core that you need to load).

So, for your specific case what you want to do is:

```
<script src="js/new/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/new/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/code.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

The `path/to/your/code.js` refers to the block of code you have above which defines the combobox widget. In terms of supporting multiple jQuery version, it doesn't matter if this is included in-page as your example does, or as an external file as my example does. The anonymous function wrapper that you have (and all plugins should have), which stores the reference to `jQuery` is what makes this work. At the time those files are executed, `jQuery` points to the correct version, and the files stores a local reference to it as `$`. Later, when you can `jQuery.noConflict(true)`, those files continue to hold their references, even though the global `jQuery` variable has changed. If you follow this pattern of invoking no conflict mode *after* loading all other files, you don't need to assign jQuery to a new variable, since all of your code will already have the necessary references. The benefit to this approach, is that you never end up with variable-specific names in your wrapper functions, and it's guaranteed to work with all existing plugins that were developed with this model, which is all official jQuery projects and likely any plugin that has thought about no conflict support.

---

One last thing: At the bottom of your script, you're referring to jQuery as `$`, but you're outside of the function wrapper that is storing the `$` reference. If this is really two separate files in your app, make sure to include the wrapper in each file. If this is actually a single script as shown above, make sure to move the document ready block inside the wrapper.